# Image size always return 0

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, image-size

I am trying to load a image from Embedded Resource to an `Image` instance. The problem is the size of the image is always 0.

Here is the code snippet:

```
Image image = new Image();
ImageSource img = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/marker.png", UriKind.Relative));
image.SetValue(Image.SourceProperty, img);


System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("output 1 = " + image.DesiredSize.Width); // return 0
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("output 2 = " + image.ActualWidth); // return 0
```

I have to know the size of the image before it rendered on the screen, because I need to offset the image depending on the size of it.

Thank you

Update:
Thanks Silvermind

I answered my own question with sample code

Comment: It has no `DesiredSize` before it is rendered on the UI.

Comment: Is it possible to get the image size before rendered on the UI?

Comment: Getting sizes of controls is not really doable before rendering see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth(v=vs.95).aspx In Silverlight it is better to think in auto positioning using HorizontalAligment and such, perhaps it is better to tell us what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am developing a map engine. I draw everything on canvas. I need to know the size of marker before drawing it on canvas, because I need to offset the position of the markers on map.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/2011/04/07/image-tips-for-windows-phone-7.aspx) could be of some help. Looks like CreateOptions might be what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Silvermind. He suggested to use CreateOptions.

Finally, I found a solution:

```
Image image = new Image();

Uri uri = new Uri("/Images/marker_stop.png", UriKind.Relative);
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(uri);
bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;

image.Source = bi;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("************************************* in image.ActualWidth " + ", " + bi.PixelWidth); // return 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [BitmapImage.DownloadProgress Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.downloadprogress(v=vs.95).aspx);

> Constructing a BitmapImage by URI is inherently asynchronous. This
>   event reports on progress of the construction.

In other words, running `ActualWidth` before the `BitmapImage` has necessarily been downloaded/constructed may very well return 0 as `ActualWidth`.

Answer (score 1):

"/Images/marker.png" - are your sure that here is the file?

maybe it is because the folder is named images without the capital I?

also what returns the:

```
image.getValue(); // here what null? after setting it
```

Comment: I am sure that the image path is correct since it can rendered on the screen.